# ¿API rest en Angular con express, en o fuera del proyecto?

Tags: angular, api, express, rest

mi duda es que tan bueno es tener una API dentro o fuera del proyecto de angular, si bien podría instalar los módulos de express dentro del proyecto de angular, también podría hacer la API en un proyecto aparte.
Sinceramente estoy aprendiendo a hacer API's y quiero resolver muchas dudas que tengo, pero no todas las encuentro resueltas. ¡De antemano gracias por las respuestas!.

Comment: Hola. Por fuera es la opción que te recomiendo. Al mantener el código separado puedes actualizar de manera independiente cada parte y cuando esta en producción no necesitas tanto trabajo.  Abra quien piense diferente pero es lo que veo en la mayoría de los proyectos. Otro punto que veo a favor es que puedes usar la misma API para diferentes plataformas (web, android, ios, etc).

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvió de mucho tu comentario!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La realidad es que cuando se realiza cualquier aplicación que conlleve Back y Front End, lo ideal seria hacer ambas cosas por separado ya que trabajar el código por separado es más practico. Para hacer actualizaciones resulta más cómodo en ambas aplicaciones.